# Does temperature affect how things slide on a slope?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, temperature, friction

Imagine I have a stainless steel slide and I roll a marble down the slope. My question is, would the marble roll down any slower or quicker if I change the temperature of either the marble or the metal slide? All are still solid state of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ball is heated, it expands. Its radius increases, therefore its moment of inertia($\propto MR^2 $) increases.
Inertia is the resistance to motion. Moment of inertia is resistance to rotation. So for the same height,  it will now roll slower and reach the bottom later.

If the slide is heated, it elongates, so it takes longer still to reach the bottom.

---

For small temperature changes $\Delta T$ at $\alpha K^{-1}m^{-1}$, it may be shown that
$$t_{new}\approx t_{old}(1+\Delta T \alpha\frac{9}{14})$$

where the numerical factor comes from the moment of inertia of the rolling body.

Comment: what about https://www.labthinkinternational.com/literatures/influence-of-temperature-on-coefficient-of-friction.html ?

Comment: I assumed other params of the system were constant. Nevertheless, during perfect rolling, the force of friction is dynamically determined so a change in coefficient of friction wouldn't matter anyways.

Comment: I took the title which says "slide". You are correct, the content says "roll"